# How I can disable the mysql binlog?

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql

Info about version:
mysql  Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Info about config:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer_size         = 16M
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
disable-log-bin
```

But, despite the presence of the string "disable-log-bin" in config, the result is:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_bin       | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

log_bin is "ON"

How can I disable it?

Comment: Strange.  Did you try `skip-log-bin`? See [Disable Binary Logs in MySQL 8.0](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72770/disable-mysql-binary-logging-with-log-bin-variable)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the correct set of config files is actually used by MySQL. Debian (and in turn Ubuntu) ships the MariaDB config files in the same directory `/etc/mysql`. Those get used by default, even if MariaDB is not installed.

You can check (and set) the relevant symlink `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` using the `update-alternatives` utility:

```bsh
update-alternatives --config my.cnf
```

Answer (score 1):

Open file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and add 1 line `disable_log_bin` after `[mysqld]`

ie.

```
[mysqld]
skip-log-bin = true
```

and upload it.

restart mysql service with sudo service mysql restart.

it's done

Comment: Thank you for your help. just little correction. we may need to follow this syntax `skip-log-bin = true`

Comment: Not tested, but the doc says that either `disable-log-bin` or `skip-log-bin` should be valid.  The answer here may have a typo with underscores instead of hyphens, which is why it may not be working.  I don't see anything about `= true` being valid or needed for either of those, though, so not sure.